# No data stored after Import CSV to oracle database

Tags: oracle, csv, sql-loader, ctl

i want to import csv file to oracle Database. 
my csv look like this :
[image]

Table A : sometimes containing 2 lines or 3 lines or empty. i want to import start Table B. so my control.ctl is :

```
echo OPTIONS (SKIP=5, errors=12000) 
     LOAD DATA  
     APPEND INTO TABLE xyz 
       when id <> '' and sales = '' 
     FIELDS TERMINATED BY X'09' 
     optionally enclosed by '"' 
     TRAILING NULLCOLS 
     (id "TRIM (:id)", 
      customer "TRIM (:customer)",
      qty "TRIM (:qty)", 
      sales filler)
```

xyz table is :

```
create xyz (
id varchar2(3),
customer varchar2(255),
qty varchar2(5)
)
```

why no data is stored?

Answer (score 0):

In Oracle, the empty string is considered `null`.  And `null` is never equal to nor unequal to any other value including `null`.  You need to use `is null` or `is not null` to look for `null` values.

The predicate

```
when id <> '' and sales = ''
```

can never possibly be true.  No `id` value is ever unequal to `null` and no `sales` value is ever equal to `null`.  Perhaps you want

```
when id is not null and sales is null
```

If you are just trying to avoid loading blank rows, however, I'd expect that your `when` clause would just be on `id` not on `sales`.